# I've been trying to output AlertDialog in flutter after someone enters something, But alertdialog doesn't work

Tags: flutter, flutter-alertdialog, flutter-textinputfield

I wanted to get an output of whatever user typed inside the textfield, I referred to official documentation of flutter dev. I couldn't come up where I am wrong, I would be really glad if you guys help. I want the textfield input as output using a controller but alertdialog doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Employee List')),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: myController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: 'Enter Employee Name',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                // When the user presses the button, show an alert dialog containing
                // the text that the user has entered into the text field.
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        // Retrieve the text that the user has entered by using the
                        // TextEditingController.
                        content: Text(myController.text),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.text_fields),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another widget(new one) or move `MaterialApp` on top level.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Employee List')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: myController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Enter Employee Name',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            // When the user presses the button, show an alert dialog containing
            // the text that the user has entered into the text field.
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    // Retrieve the text that the user has entered by using the
                    // TextEditingController.
                    content: Text(myController.text),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.text_fields),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, Really helpful. Can you explain why this happened ?

Comment: glad to help, I am also looking for the git issue that will explain much better. The concept i think to have different context